# Как можно создать кривые линии между блоками?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Создаю приложение используя Jepack Compose, но столкнулся с проблемой. В приложении требуется рисовать кривые линии и ими соединять блоки друг с другом, встроенного функционала не нашёл, поэтому пришлось самому пытаться придумывать решение

**Моя проблема и попытка её исправить:**
Не могу адекватно рисовать кривые линии между блоками в родительском контейнере. Я попытался генерировать линии между блоками, так:

- Я начал по удержанию пользователя генерировать полосу, под которой генерируется canvas, чтобы грубо говоря, canvas был над родительским контейнером и его начало и конец соединяли два блока

  ```
  @Composable
  fun DrawingScreen() {
   var path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path()) }
   var lineThickness by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
   var canvasSize by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
   var isDrawing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   Box(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
   ) {
       Box(
           modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth()
               .height(100.dp)
               .background(Color.White)
               .pointerInput(Unit) {
                   detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                       val x = change.position.x
                       val y = change.position.y
                       if (change.pressure > 0.1f) {
                           path.lineTo(x, y)
                           lineThickness = change.pressure * 30
                           if (!isDrawing) {
                               isDrawing = true
                               canvasSize = 0
                           }
                       } else {
                           path.moveTo(x, y)
                       }
                       canvasSize = max(canvasSize, path.getBounds().width.toInt())
                   }
               }
       )
       if (isDrawing) {
           Canvas(
               modifier = Modifier
                   .size(canvasSize.dp, canvasSize.dp)
                   .offset(y = 100.dp)
           ) {
               drawPath(
                   path = path,
                   color = Color.Black,
                   alpha = 1f,
                   style = Stroke(width = lineThickness)
               )
           }
       }
   }
  }
  ```

*Возможно вы скажете, что это какое-то извращение? Полностью с вами согласен, но не очень понимаю, какой ещё подход можно применить, рефернс брал с Blueprint(скриншот прикрепил ниже).*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Проблема:** к сожалению адекватно генерировать Canvas под стрелкой у меня не получается. Подскажите, возможно я неверно подошёл к этой задаче или возможно существует готовое api для работы с такого рода вещами

Comment: Не выглядит как извращение, но зачем canvas создавать по тапу? Можно иметь изначально, а по тапу в нём рисовать.

Comment: Тогда не очень ясно, как именно в нём размещать блоки, как будто они должны быть поверх canvas, но тогда проблема в том, что не очень понятно, как понимать, что два блока связаны

Comment: Попробуйте сделать один большой CustomView и в нем рисовать все.